# All files have execute permission in Fedora 21

Tags: linux, permissions

A few mouths ago i accidentally deleted my home folder, after that accident all files have execute permission, even those which are mounted in `/run/media/...`. Default action on opening files is to run them as shell scripts instead of opening them in gedit or geany.

It may sound funny, i double clicked on a python `requirements.txt` file and there was `Django>=1.8` in the file, suddenly an empty file named `=1.8` got created!

```
ll /run/media/mjafar/Data/OSImages:

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mjafar mjafar  727711744 اوت    4  2014 elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso
drwxrwxrwx. 1 mjafar mjafar       4096 سپتام 18 13:16 Fedora
-rwxrwxrwx. 2 mjafar mjafar 3028680704 سپتام 27  2014 kali-linux-1.0.9-amd64.iso
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mjafar mjafar  732213248 آوریل 25  2012 ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mjafar mjafar 1010827264 آوریل 21  2014 ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso


uname -a:

Linux mjafar-vaio 4.1.7-100.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 21:46:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*EDIT 1:* It happens on both ext4 (/, /home, ...) and NTFS drives.

*EDIT 2:*

```
ll /etc :


total 2028
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 abrt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       18 فوریه 20  2015 adjtime
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 aircrack-ng
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1518 آوریل 24  2014 aliases
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 alsa
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 13 10:06 alternatives
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      541 سپتام 18  2014 anacrontab
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       55 اوت   16  2014 asound.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        1 اكتبر 10  2014 at.deny
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 at-spi2
drwxr-x---.  3 root root     4096 سپتام  1 20:19 audisp
drwxr-x---.  3 root root     4096 سپتام  1 20:19 audit
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 avahi
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل 15 21:23 ax25
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     3770 اوت   16  2014 axelrc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 26 19:05 bash_completion.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2837 فوریه 23  2015 bashrc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن   9 18:10 binfmt.d
-rw-r-----.  1 root brlapi     33 دسامب  4  2014 brlapi.key
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root     4096 مه    25 15:52 brltty
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    22899 مه    25 15:52 brltty.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 نوامب  5  2014 chkconfig.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1165 آوریل  7 19:05 chrony.conf
-rw-r-----.  1 root chrony    111 فوریه 20  2015 chrony.keys
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 cifs-utils
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 corosync
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:11 cron.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام  1 20:25 cron.daily
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 سپتام 18  2014 cron.deny
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:04 cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 12  2014 cron.monthly
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      451 ژوئیه 12  2014 crontab
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 12  2014 cron.weekly
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 02:57 crypto-policies
-rw-------.  1 root root        0 فوریه 20  2015 crypttab
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1602 آوریل 24  2014 csh.cshrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      841 آوریل 24  2014 csh.login
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root lp       4096 سپتام 28 22:10 cups
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 cupshelpers
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 dbus-1
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 dconf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 00:43 default
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 نوامب 16  2014 depmod.d
drwxr-x---.  3 root root     4096 فوریه  3  2015 dhcp
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5081 مه    14 17:31 DIR_COLORS
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5697 مه    14 17:31 DIR_COLORS.256color
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5102 مه    14 17:31 DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1131 فوریه 24  2015 dleyna-server-service.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 dnf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    26125 اكتبر  6  2014 dnsmasq.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اكتبر  6  2014 dnsmasq.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1285 مه    18 16:33 dracut.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 مه    18 16:33 dracut.conf.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     3739 مارس  23  2015 drirc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      115 مه     1 06:06 e2fsck.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 فوریه 23  2015 environment
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1362 اوت   16  2014 ethertypes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 آوریل 24  2014 exports
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  26 19:28 exports.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       30 اكتبر  9  2014 extlinux.conf -> ../boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       56 نوامب 20  2014 favicon.png -> /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/fedora-logo-icon.png
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 fcoe
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       31 نوامب 22  2014 fedora-release
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 festival
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       66 فوریه 23  2015 filesystems
drwxr-x---.  5 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:21 firewalld
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 fonts
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 foomatic
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       20 فوریه  3  2015 fprintd.conf
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root      662 ژوئیه 30 11:38 fstab
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       38 مه    23 00:51 fuse.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 gconf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل  3 19:22 gcrypt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      265 ژوئن  26 18:12 gdbinit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  26 18:12 gdbinit.d
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 gdm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 geoclue
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1284 آوریل 14 01:42 GeoIP.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 00:33 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئیه 17 20:09 gimp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن   3 01:10 gnupg
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       94 آوریل  7 13:48 GREP_COLORS
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 groff
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1099 سپتام 10 23:47 group
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1081 ژوئیه 28 21:19 group-
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       22 دسامب  5  2014 grub2.cfg -> ../boot/grub2/grub.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       31 دسامب  5  2014 grub2-efi.cfg -> ../boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
drwx------.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 grub.d
----------.  1 root root      892 سپتام 10 23:47 gshadow
----------.  1 root root      877 ژوئیه 28 21:18 gshadow-
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 مه     6 05:08 gss
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 00:32 gssproxy
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 gtk
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      871 دسامب  4  2014 hba.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:23 highlight
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        9 آوریل 24  2014 host.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       12 مه    31 10:54 hostname
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       83 دسامب  4  2014 hosts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      370 آوریل 24  2014 hosts.allow
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      460 آوریل 24  2014 hosts.deny
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 hp
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 httpd
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     3580 نوامب  5  2014 idmapd.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    4 18:27 ImageMagick-6
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       11 نوامب  5  2014 init.d -> rc.d/init.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      490 ژوئن   9 18:10 inittab
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      942 آوریل 24  2014 inputrc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 iproute2
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 iscsi
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       56 نوامب 22  2014 issue
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       55 نوامب 22  2014 issue.net
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:01 java
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل 23 14:17 jvm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل 23 14:17 jvm-commmon
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    70878 اوت    2 17:31 jwhois.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     4096 ژوئن  19 12:03 kde
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     7156 فوریه 21  2015 kdump.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 kernel
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      495 مه     6 04:58 krb5.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   127211 سپتام 26 19:08 ld.so.cache
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       28 فوریه 27  2015 ld.so.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 26 19:08 ld.so.conf.d
-rw-r-----.  1 root root      191 اوت   14 01:26 libaudit.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت   17  2014 libibverbs.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 02:56 libnl
drw-------.  2 root root     4096 ژانوی 30  2015 liboath
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 libreport
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2391 ژوئیه 23 23:46 libuser.conf
drwx------.  4 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 libvirt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      131 آوریل 11 23:02 locale.conf
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       33 فوریه 20  2015 localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2028 اوت   18  2014 login.defs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      662 اوت    1  2012 logrotate.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 logrotate.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 lsb-release.d
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 lvm
-r--r--r--.  1 root root       33 فوریه 20  2015 machine-id
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       28 مه    31 10:54 machine-info
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      111 ژوئن  22 10:51 magic
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      272 اكتبر 14  2014 mailcap
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1968 دسامب 18  2014 mail.rc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5122 ژانوی 13  2015 makedumpfile.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5168 اوت    4 19:22 man_db.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل 23 14:17 maven
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:04 mcelog
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    55262 اكتبر 14  2014 mime.types
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      956 مه     1 06:08 mke2fs.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 مارس   2  2015 modulefiles
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن   9 18:10 modules-load.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 آوریل 24  2014 motd
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       17 فوریه 20  2015 mtab -> /proc/self/mounts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2620 اوت   17  2014 mtools.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 19  2015 multipath
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 25 15:53 nas
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      767 آوریل 24 19:42 netconfig
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root     4096 مه    11 13:15 NetworkManager
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       58 فوریه 24  2015 networks
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     3605 ژوئن  26 19:28 nfsmount.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1758 ژوئن  16 03:02 nsswitch.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1758 فوریه 21  2015 nsswitch.conf.bak
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 02:58 openldap
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    4 23:53 openvpn
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 نوامب 18  2014 opt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      377 نوامب 22  2014 os-release
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 26 19:05 PackageKit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام  1 20:19 pam.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 pam_pkcs11
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2627 سپتام 10 23:47 passwd
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2548 ژوئن  16 03:03 passwd-
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       99 مارس  14  2010 passwdqc.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 pcmcia
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     2872 اوت   18  2014 pinforc
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 pkcs11
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root     4096 نوامب 18  2014 pki
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     4096 نوامب 18  2014 pm
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     4096 ژوئیه 15 01:56 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت   18  2014 popt.d
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 ppp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 prelink.conf.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      233 آوریل 24  2014 printcap
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1750 آوریل 24  2014 profile
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 26 19:05 profile.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     6545 آوریل 24  2014 protocols
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     3668 ژوئن  15 18:52 proxychains.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:16 pulse
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:04 purple
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام  5 21:27 qemu
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      433 اوت   18  2014 radvd.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1018 سپتام 16  2008 rarfiles.lst
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc0.d -> rc.d/rc0.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc1.d -> rc.d/rc1.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc2.d -> rc.d/rc2.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc3.d -> rc.d/rc3.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc4.d -> rc.d/rc4.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc5.d -> rc.d/rc5.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       10 فوریه 24  2015 rc6.d -> rc.d/rc6.d
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root     4096 فوریه 24  2015 rc.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 redhat-lsb
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       14 نوامب 22  2014 redhat-release -> fedora-release
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1787 اوت   17  2014 request-key.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 request-key.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       57 سپتام 29 10:43 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1634 سپتام  7  2014 rpc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  15 11:40 rpm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      458 اوت   18  2014 rsyncd.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 rsyslog.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      927 فوریه 24  2015 rwtab
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 21:59 rwtab.d
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     5109 ژانوی 24  2015 rygel.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 samba
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:17 sane.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام  5 21:27 sasl2
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 scl
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 سپتام 13 10:01 security
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 ژوئیه 21 16:22 selinux
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   678560 فوریه 23  2015 services
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      216 ژوئن  26 17:55 sestatus.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:03 setroubleshoot
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 setuptool.d
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 دسامب 15  2014 sgml
----------.  1 root root     1402 سپتام 10 23:47 shadow
----------.  1 root root     1376 ژوئن  16 03:03 shadow-
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       76 آوریل 24  2014 shells
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 سپتام  5 21:27 skel
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1272 اوت   17  2014 smi.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      256 ژوئن  18  2014 sos.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:19 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام  1 20:19 ssh
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 سپتام 17 19:48 ssl
drwxr-s---.  2 root mail     4096 فوریه 21  2015 ssmtp
drwx------.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 21 12:14 sssd
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      212 فوریه 24  2015 statetab
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 24  2015 statetab.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن   8 19:06 stunnel
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 16 17:44 subversion
-r--r-----.  1 root root     3253 مارس  12  2014 sudoers
drwxr-x---.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 18  2015 sudoers.d
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 سپتام 28 11:36 sysconfig
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      504 فوریه 21  2015 sysctl.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      449 فوریه  5  2015 sysctl.conf.insyncbak
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 sysctl.d
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 systemd
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       14 نوامب 22  2014 system-release -> fedora-release
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       31 نوامب 22  2014 system-release-cpe
-rw-------.  1 tss  tss      7046 اوت   19  2014 tcsd.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت   18  2014 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن   9 18:10 tmpfiles.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 tor
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       45 مه    10  2012 Trolltech.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      375 ژوئیه 29 17:23 trusted-key.key
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 سپتام 25 09:47 udev
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  30 17:50 udisks2
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:03 unbound
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      521 مه    26 16:23 updatedb.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 03:02 UPower
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      888 مه    30  2014 usb_modeswitch.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    16384 ژوئن  16 03:08 usb_modeswitch.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:18 vbox
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       33 آوریل 11 23:02 vconsole.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       51 مارس  17  2015 vdpau_wrapper.cfg
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1982 اوت   25 14:02 vimrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     1982 اوت   25 14:02 virc
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:16 vmware-tools
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 vpnc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     4925 مارس  10  2015 wgetrc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 اوت    5 22:00 wpa_supplicant
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root        0 اوت   19  2014 wvdial.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 نوامب 18  2014 X11
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      589 اوت   16  2014 xattr.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root     4096 ژوئیه 28 21:16 xdg
-rw-------.  1 root root     1001 اوت   19  2014 xinetd.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 آوریل 15 21:23 xinetd.d
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 فوریه 21  2015 xml
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root       63 سپتام 20 22:38 youtube-dl.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root     4096 دسامب  4  2014 yum
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      813 ژوئن  16 00:47 yum.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 ژوئن  16 00:48 yum.repos.d
```

And:

```
lsblk -o +FSTYPE:

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT             FSTYPE
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk                        
├─sda1    8:1    0    14G  0 part                        ntfs
├─sda2    8:2    0   100M  0 part                        ntfs
├─sda3    8:3    0 167.4G  0 part                        ntfs
├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part                        
├─sda5    8:5    0    50G  0 part                        ntfs
├─sda6    8:6    0 148.1G  0 part /run/media/mjafar/Data ntfs
├─sda7    8:7    0   249M  0 part /boot                  ext4
├─sda8    8:8    0    28G  0 part /                      ext4
├─sda9    8:9    0    50G  0 part /home                  ext4
└─sda10   8:10   0     8G  0 part [SWAP]                 swap
```

Comment: give us the output of umask command please

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene 0002

Comment: what kind of filesystem is this? its not FAT or NTFS is it?

Comment: would you please run "ls -l /etc"  and "lsblk -o +FSTYPE" and post the results.

Comment: @FrankThomas It's ntfs and ext4

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene edited the post :)

Comment: what is the line in your `/etc/fstab` for `/dev/sda6` ? Usually permissions on NTFS volumes are assigned at mount, since the filesystem itself has no way to store foreign (linux) permissions.

Comment: Please clarify, whats wrong with your /etc/ ? some files are executable some are not.

Comment: @FrankThomas there's no entry for `sda6` in `fstab`. There are only four entries for my 4 ext4 partitions

Comment: so how do you mount sda6? is it from script? if so we want to see the mount command and its parameters for mounting that disk.

Comment: @FrankThomas I mount them after boot, by clicking on them in nautilus or using `mount` command in terminal

Comment: ok what is the exact mount command you enter?

Comment: Well, gnome uses this command: `# mkdir -p /run/media/mjafar/Data && mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda6" "/run/media/mjafar/Data"`

Comment: add `umask=011` if you want the files com come out as 766 or `umask=111` if you want them to come out as 666.